# Why a 5hp 14" table saw?

Tags: table-saw, power-tools, cutting, rip-cut

Is a DIYer who works on smaller projects, such as cabinets, desks, lamps, etc., would I have any benefit from owning a 5hp 14" Powermatic saw? More specifically, it is pretty clear that a saw like this will give me a greater depth of cut. But will it also make it easier to make smaller cuts and will the end result be better?

Comment: You don't even need a table saw much less a 5hp model, just sayin' ;-)

Comment: To help frame some of the answers that follow, 5 h.p is a little over 3.7 kW, and energy (watts) is calculated as voltage (volts) multiplied by current (amperes). So a 110 volt electricity supply would need to deliver about 34 amps to power a 5 hp motor; a 240 volt supply would need to deliver about 16 amps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a DIYer, there's no compelling reason for you to go out shopping for a 14" table saw. That said, if you're asking because there happens to be a 14" table saw available to you for an irresistible price, there's nothing inherently *wrong* with it, but there are some things to be aware of:

- If you're in the US, **you won't be able to get 5 hp out of a standard wall socket**, so you'll need to have the right electrical supply available. At *minimum*, it'll require 220 V service. But more likely than that, it'll require a [3-phase power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase), which pretty much only exists in a commercial or industrial setting. Check the specifications of the machine and make sure that the electrical power you have available will work for this saw.
- It'll be heavier, and more difficult to get into position in your shop.
- Blades and accessories will be more expensive.

Mainly, the advantages that come with a larger saw blade are the depth of cut you can achieve (see note), but cut *quality* is tied more to how carefully and precisely your machine is set up, not how big the blade is, so it wouldn't necessarily make your end result any better. I don't see how it would make smaller cuts any easier.

Note: a saw this size is an expensive, professional machine. As such, it'll probably have nice features and great build quality, but those are more related to it being a professional machine than the fact that it has a large blade.

Comment: It might require 3 phase power - I'd be surprised if it didn't.

Comment: @CoAstroGeek That's a great point, thanks for thinking of it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You can get phase converters to run 3 phase tools in a home shop.  But you'd have to have a really compelling need for a 14" saw to go that route.  If you have to ask why you would need a 14" saw, you don't need a 14" saw!

That said - a 220V 3HP 12" cabinet saw is a joy to use compared to a typical contractor or benchtop saw.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_phase_converter

Comment: @CoAstroGeek these days you can get 3-phase inverters as well

Answer (score -1):

You could cut some really big coves!